# create directory error while not entering into if condition

Tags: c#

I have a problem with directory creation:

```
if (!Directory.Exists(directorypath)//here i have that problem not enter into if contion 
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(directorypath);
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Successfully Saved');", true);
}
else
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Directory Already Exists');", true);
}
```

Comment: Take sure the path is correct. Also surround it by try { } catch { } and get inner exception details

Comment: You need to provide more details. For example as it stands not entering into the first part of the if condition is quite reasonable if the directory exists. Does the directory exist? Have you verified the directorypath is correct and the one you expect? What is your directory path? Are you using relative paths or something else?

Comment: I assume the missing parenthesis on the first line is a typo here and not in your actual code?

Comment: Use a try{} catch{} statement and a breakpoint...see what is the directorypath value...

Answer (score 0):

Can you please do like this ?

```
try
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(directorypath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(directorypath);
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Successfully Saved');", true);
    }
    else
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Directory Already Exists');", true);
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw;
}
```

I believe you have problem with parenthesis on very first line, and please make sure that `directorypath` has valid path